# Why does it get nothing that Getting private Properties? (c#)

Tags: c#, reflection, private, protected, getproperty

```
public class A{
    public Info m_Info = new Info();
    Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m_Info.Property_Count());
    }
    public class Info{

        protected int i_Id;
        protected string s_Name; 

        public int Property_Count(){
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] data = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

            foreach(var item in data)
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            return data.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

**I am trying to get private or protected properties~**
but data.Length always return 0, sounds like it get nothing, why it?

Comment: About fields and properties of a class: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_properties.htm and https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class doesn't have any [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). These:

```
protected int i_Id;
protected string s_Name;
```

are [*fields*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). You can either change them to properties:

```
protected int i_Id { get; set; }
protected string s_Name { get; set; }
```

or you can use [`GetFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=net-5.0):

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] data = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
```